# Can crawlers access 'Deny From All' directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, googlebot

Hello in my site I have a core folder, in which there is sensitive data, in which I have a htaccess file with 'Deny From All'. My question is can Google or some other crawler access that directory even when they know I don't want anyone there?

Comment: If you have access to the http servers configuration then put such rules into the main configuration, not into .htaccess style files. It is safer and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, no, they cannot access it. But by placing the folder there (under a public directory) you expose yourself to a higher risk, like if you make a mistake and overwrite your .htaccess , or the server gets updated and your rules became ineffective.

You'd be better to move that folder outside of your `public_html` (or equivalent). What I usually do is to create a `private_files` right beside the `public_html` folder, and any files that I need there can be referenced from (secure!) scripts.

Comment: You mean the place where I have: public_html, public_ftp, tmp, www, mail and few others? That's where I should keep the directories?

Comment: Yep, in my case, public_html, public_ftp and private_files are all on the same level. That way, there's no need for .htaccess since the files ARE NOT accessible publicly. Any scripts that needs those files must be secure tough.

Comment: What do you mean by 'any scripts that needs those files must be securr tough' Can I do something like this in my index.php: require '/../private_files/connection/database.php';   ?

Comment: Exactly, you can `include()`, `require()`, `fopen()`, `file_get_contents()` (etc.) using relative paths. Unless your host is really badly configured (using open_basedir restrictions set to the `public_html` instead of your user's home directory) you should be alright.

Answer (score 1):

No they can't. Bots can choose whether to follow instructions from robots.txt and such but they cannot skip what the server is throwing at them. In other words, the server will refuse to display that information and there's nothing ( Well supposedly ) that the bot can do about this. Good luck :P

Comment: So you mean they can't access them even if they don't want to listen to me? Also do you think it is a good idea to have that directory in the robots.txt file, to stop them from accessing those folder, or you think it is not required?

Comment: It is not a good idea to have directories you want to protect in your robots.txt because only good bots follow rules from this file. Bad bots will most certainly not and will even help them recognize important directories. As to if they "don't want to listen", as I said, it's not up to them when the server is refusing to display the information! :P